# Infopath rules on form load, multiple values in a multiple selection box in 1 rule

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I have a multiple selection list box and I want to set up a rule when the form loads. The rule just ticks the boxes of 2 values that are already in the box.
Is it possible to do this in one rule? I can input one value in the rule but when I try to add another separated with a comma, semi colon or a space. It just creates a new value. is there anyway of doing this in one rule? sp2010